# Creating a method that could allow me to change my user's post content in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, helper

So im creating a website, and on that website people can post links. Depending on what the link is, the post will render differently. For example, a post with a link to youtube.com/somevideo will render an embeded video. A link ending in JPG will display that image.

I have written the following in my view

```
    <% link_type = extract_content_from_url(post.link)  %>
    <div class ="preview_of_post">
    
        <% if post.link %>
            <% if link_type == "youtube" %>
                <%= youtube_embed(post.link) %>
            <% end %>
            <br />
            <%= link_to (post.link), (post.link) %>
        <% end %>
```

And in my helper, I have this:

```
module PostsHelper
  def extract_content_from_url(url) 
    if url != ""
      unless url.include?("http://")
        post.link = "http://#{post.link.downcase}"
      end
    else
      return "nil"
    end
        
    if url.include? == "youtube.com/watch" #youtube link
      return "youtube"
    end
    
    if File.extname(url) == ".gif" || File.extname(url) == ".jpg" || 
       File.extname(url) == ".png" || File.extname(url) == ".jpeg"
       return"picture"
    end
  end
  
  
  def youtube_embed(youtube_url)
    if youtube_url[/youtu\.be\/([^\?]*)/]
      youtube_id = $1
    else
      youtube_url[/^.*((v\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^\&\?]*).*/]
      youtube_id = $5
    end
    render(:inline=> "<iframe title='YouTube video player' width='640' height='390' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/#{ youtube_id }' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>")
  end
end
```

When running my code, I get the following error:

[image]

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: You should checkout https://github.com/judofyr/ruby-oembed and http://embed.ly/

Answer (score 1):

`url.include? == "youtube.com/watch"` is not valid. `include?` is a method which takes an argument. You probably mean `url.include? "youtube.com/watch"`.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the youtube videos. But now when I post a non-youtube video, I get this error

"undefined local variable or method `post' for #<#<Class:0x007fc56e091790>:0x007fc56be3ee40>"

for this:

"30:    <% link_type = extract_content_from_url(post.link)  %>"

Comment: You need to pass the `post` variable into your helper function.

Comment: And the post variable in you view needs to be defined...  perhap you mean @post from the controller?